# Can't install TensorFlow via pip3

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pip

I am currently trying to set up TensorFlow on Ubuntu via EC2, however I was having an issue where when I whenever I upgraded pip3 and tried to install TensorFlow, I would get a 'killed' at the end of the download.
I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong but based on some googling, some thoughts were possibly a pathing issue?

[Photo of killed error(?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lFkH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running low on memory :

```
pip3 install tensorflow --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, should I be concerned about pathing issues at all?

Comment: Not at all its just like disabling cache in your browser to save memory